# Writing a string to disk without any character conversion in Groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a String object, now because it comes a diff of a folder containing different file types, not everything in it is encoded in the same character set.

The correct codes are in the string, but whenever I try to access the string, groovy tries to be helpful and decode the string, which messes things up.

Now the following seems to do what I need

```
String decoded_diff = "String that contains codes from different character encodings"
patch_file_name = 'changes.patch'
patch_file =  new File(pwd(), patch_file_name)
patch_file.delete()
max_block_size = 1024 * 1024
char[] char_buffer = new char[max_block_size]
block_start = 0
patch_length = decoded_diff.length()
while (true) {
    block_size = Math.min(patch_length - block_start, max_block_size)
    decoded_diff.getChars(block_start, block_start + block_size, char_buffer, 0)
    block_start += block_size
    byte[] byte_buffer = new byte[block_size]
    for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
        byte_buffer[i] = (int) char_buffer[i]
    }
    patch_file.append(byte_buffer)
    if (block_start == patch_length) break
}
```

However, it is sloooow

Is there a faster way to achieve the same thing? The final patch file must be identical to the original diff to work. Unfortunately I can't send the file itself (jenkins currently doesn't support file parameters in pipeline jobs) so I have to escape it and send it as part of a json parameter list, hence this painful rigmarole on the receiving end.

Comment: Why not read the files as bytes? Instead of reading into string ?

Comment: I'm not reading a file. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough when I said I coudn't send the file. This code is on the receiving end, so that String object actually comes from a json object in a form in a POST request.

Comment: Oh, and when I say it's slow, I mean it. It's been working on a 400k file for and hour and 10 minutes now, that makes absolutely no sense to me. is it something to do with the fact that it's running inside jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
String decoded_diff = "String that contains codes from different character encodings"
patch_file_name = 'changes.patch'
patch_file =  new File(pwd(), patch_file_name)
patch_file.delete()

patchFile.withOutputStream { os ->
    os << decoded_diff.bytes
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is crashing. An Error Occured java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BufferedOutputStream
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BufferedOutputStream
 at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:860)
 at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)

Comment: @JonHodgson Ahhh, it's probably trying to serialize the return value of the script...  Try adding `null` as a last line after the `}`

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of that, but it doesn't help. I have found that with Groovy inside Jenkins, some things don't work as expected, which makes life even harder for a newbie to Groovy

Comment: Looks like it might be this https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables

Comment: Try setting `os` to null after using it?